# What's the difference between 海洋 and 大洋?

Tags: word-choice, words

According to my dictionary they both mean "ocean", but I guess there is a reason for both words to exist. Am I right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

海洋 is simply a technical/scientific version of 海. In scientific contexts, 大洋 specifically refers to the five [**global oceans**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Ocean) on the earth, namely 太平洋 (The Pacific Ocean), 大西洋 (The Atlantic Ocean), インド洋 (The Indian Ocean), 北極海 (The Arctic Ocean), and 南極海 (The Southern Ocean). Imagine 大洋 is a oceanic version of 大陸 (continent). See [this Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E6%B4%8B).

Outside scientific contexts, 大洋 is not a common word. It's possible to use it simply in the sense of "big ocean", but I think 大海 is much more commonly used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

They both mean "ocean" indeed but because of 大, 大洋 makes a listener think of big vast ocean, whereas 海洋 covers all kinds of seas big and small, such as 海洋生物 (marine life) or 海洋資源 (marine resources)

Answer (score 1):

Basically agrees with Naruto’s answer. Here is an explanation from kotobank.jp:

> 海洋 かいよう ocean
>
> 地球表面の陸地以外の水をたたえた凹所で，水は塩分の組成が一定の海水である。海洋の総面積は約 3.6億km²で，陸地の約 2.4倍。海洋は大洋と付属海に分けられる。大洋は面積が広く，独立の海流系をもつ海で，太平洋，大西洋，インド洋の三つに分けることが多い。付属海は大洋の海流の影響を受ける海で，浅くて独立の海流系がない。付属海は地中海と縁海に二分される。

Therefore 海洋 means *ocean*, as opposed to *land*, and it includes 大洋 (Pacific, Atlantic, etc.) and 付属海 (adjacent sea).